# Extracting data from filenames in Gnuplot

Tags: string, variables, gnuplot

Is there a way for Gnuplot to read and recognize structured strings? Specifically, I have a few hundred files, all containing measurement data, with measurement conditions defined in the filename.

My files look something like "100d5mK2d0T.txt", which would mean that this data was acquired at 100.5mK temperature and 2.0T magnetic field.

Any chance I could extract the temperature and field strength data from the name, and use them as labels in the plot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running your gnuplot script--interactively or calling a canned script repeatedly?  Also, what OS/gnuplot version are you using?

Comment: I would suggest to use external parser. Gnuplot has the c-like `sprintf` function but not the `scanf`. Nevertheless some string manipulation is possible. As example `name="100d5mK2d0T.txt"; temp = int(name[0:3])+int(name[5:6])/10.0; Bfield = int(name[8:9])+int(name[10:11])/10.0` will do what you want, but this implies the formatting is strictly fixed... It would'n work for strings like `99d5mK2d05T.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gnuplot's internal string processing you could come up with a solution (using `substr` and `strstrt`), but thats quite verbose.

Its better to use an external tool for the string processing, like perl:

```
filename = '100d5mK2d0T.txt'
str = system('echo "'.filename. '" | perl -pe ''s/(\d+)d(\d+)mK(\d+)d(\d+)T.txt/\1.\2 \3.\4/'' ')
temperature = word(str, 1)
magnetic_field = word(str, 2)

set label at graph 0.1,0.9 "Temperature: ".temperature." mK"
set label at graph 0.1,0.8 "Magnetic field: ".magnetic_field." T"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! One more detail, if you don't mind. Besides the useful information, filenames also carry some junk at the end. Something like "49d0mKnow_50d0mKset_3d00T_D03_1_240_001.dat". So, I would like to extract the second temperature and the magnetic field, while ignoring everything else.

I managed to do so by modifying your code a bit:
`perl -pe ''s/(\d+)d(\d+)mKnow_(\d+)d(\d+)mKset_(\d+)d(\d+)T(\s)*/\1.\2 \3.\4 \5.\6 \7/''`

I'm not really familiar with Perl syntax, so I just wanted to ask if this is okay, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm also not very familier with perl, just with regular expressions. As long as it works, its fine :) Depending on the different formats which your file names can have, it may be easier to use one `perl` call for each variable instead of extracting all together and then splitting them with `word` inside gnuplot.